# how to disable ssl cert check in gatling project?

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a code as below

```html
class BasicSimulation extends Simulation {
  val feeder = csv("PerfData.csv").random
  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl(System.getProperty("ServiceUrl"))
  System.setProperty("gatling.http.ahc.useOpenSsl", "false");

  val scn = scenario("Track Doc Ingestion service").feed(feeder)
    .exec(http("Default Request")
    .post("/trackdocs").header("Content-Encoding", "gzip").body(RawFileBody("track-12b1190f-fa5f-4c7e-b328-39c1e250aa51.xml.gzip")).check(status.is(200)))


  setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("users"))) during (Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("duration")))).protocols(httpProtocol))
```

when i run this, i am getting below error

```html
 [gatling-http-1-2][WARN ][StatsProcessor.scala:84] i.g.h.e.r.DefaultStatsProcessor - Request 'query Request' failed for user 1: status.find.is(200), but actually found 500
Session(Track Doc api service querying,1,1599167198666,Map(gatling.http.cache.baseUrl -> https://localhost:48080, gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.cache.DnsCacheSupport$$anon$1@5b147857, accountId -> L1TL1N, gatling.http.ssl.sslContexts -> SslContexts(io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext@35ce16a9,None), executionId -> execution-asasas2-efc2b531e69a-2020.09.03),31,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$558/0x00000001005f1040@29c99b9e)
```

how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

> Request 'query Request' failed for user 1: status.find.is(200), but actually found 500

You're getting a response with a 500 status code. This has absolutely nothing to do with SSL certificate validation.